# Can I use the mean value of a dummy variable the same way I would use a dummy variable?

Tags: cross-section

My dataset is composed of various country-level observations over the years. I am interested in the cross-sectionnal dimension of my database rather than the time series aspect. For this reason, I decided to turn this panel dataset into a cross sectional one. To do this, for each variable, I take the mean value of each country over the years. For example, instead of observing Germany's GDP t times, I observe Germany's GDP one time, its value being the mean GDP of Germany over t years.

The problem is, some of my variables are dummies, taking either 0 or 1 as a value (for example, the variable "Democracy" is a dummy). If I use the mean value of "Democracy" for each country as an independant variable in my regression, will the fact that it is not a dummy anymore cause a problem ? If I want to observe the impact of being a democratic country or not on my dependant variable, can I leave this variable as is, or should I find a way to turn this variable back to a dummy ?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not a dummy anymore"?

Comment: It can take some values other than just 0 and 1, making it a continuous variable bounded between 0 and 1.

Comment: But why would this be a problem? Are you asking if you are allowed to use % data as features in the model?

Comment: I am asking if the mean value of a dummy variable has any sense in terms of interpretation. A dummy variable is supposed to have only two values. But when you take the mean of a dummy variable over time, this isn't the case anymore (for example, in my dataset, Pakistan has a "Democracy" value of 0.75). Thus, can I still interpret the coefficient of the mean of democracy (a continuous variable between 0 and 1) as I would the coefficient of democracy (a dummy, taking values 0 or 1) ?